# Angularjs cache compiled DOM element with scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, caching

### Angularjs cache compiled DOM element with scope

Context is I am working on the mobile environment,so i try to cache the compiled DOM element into memory like this:

```
cache[key] = $compile(myTemplate)(newScope);
```

and update the other element's content like this:

```
$('myElement').html(cache[key]);
```

the first time everything work well, and then i clear myElement's content and use the cache to update myElement's content again like this:

```
$('myElement').empty().html(cache[key]);
```

and the scope of the cached compiled template disappear(the scope of the cache[key]).

I don't want use:

```
 $compile(myTemplate)(scope, function(compiledTemplate) {
  cache[key] = compiledTemplate;
});
```

to compile template and apply to scope every time, so if there any way can cache the compiled Dom element with scope, please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little bit late, but it might help others.

Give a try to https://github.com/rotorgames/angular-rg-cache-view

it seems to cache views while keeping the scope.